# How i can get specific words from string?

Tags: php, string

I have different strings like England: Premier League,England: Championship,England: Championship - Play Offs  i want to show some short hand like ENG-prl,ENG-ch how i can get in php?

Comment: Please make more efforts when asking a question. At least tag a language.. We are not mind readers.

Comment: $arr=explode(":", $cate["name"]);
        $short_name=end($arr);
        echo $short_name; 
this is what i tried and got 
World Cup - Qualification - Third Stage
World Cup - Qualification - Second Stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$str=explode(":","England: Premier League");

$result1 = substr(trim($str[0]), 0, 3);

$result2 = substr(trim($str[1]), 0, 3);

echo $result1."-".$result2;
```